# How can I prevent copy elision?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `sfract` which stores a pointer to the root node of a binary tree. Obviously when copy-constructing an `sfract` I need to clone the binary tree of the other `sfract` object. However, the copy constructor is never called, I think because of copy elision. This causes two `sfract` objects to refer to, and attempt to deallocate, the same root node on deconstruction. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
//main.cpp
sfract_type a( /*...*/ );
sfract_type b( /*...*/ );
sfract_type c( a ); // copy construct

//sfract.h
template< class FType, class Alloc >
sfract( sfract< FType, Alloc > const & other )
{
    // Clone other's root node and assign to this object
    root = other.root->clone();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler? GCC has a flag and I presume Clang uses the same one.

Comment: VS2010 unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with copy elision. Can you show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Copy-elision makes the returned object be constructed in-place rather than copied, it should not have the effect you mention. Please post a minimal piece of code that repros your issue.

Comment: You don't need to prevent copy elision. If your class' copy constructor has sideeffects such as the one you show here, it should just Do The Right Thing. But since you don't show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), we can only guess what's the real problem here.

Comment: Your templated copy constructor will cover cases where FType and Alloc are different from that of your class, but if they are the same your default copy constructor will be invoked. Override that too.

Comment: @CashCow That was it! It seems stupidly obvious now. I added a non-template copy constructor and the copying was done correctly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot see your code, but your templated constructor is not going to take precedence over the default copy constructor, and therefore in the case where FType and Alloc match that of your class, the default one will be invoked.

You have two options:

1. Overload that too.
2. Derive your template (possibly protected) from a non-templated base class that manages that part of the copy/clone. That can often be better as you have a single class managing the "root" member.

And of course because you are overloading your copy-constructor ensure your assignment operators are also correctly handled (as well as the destructor).

Comment: That fixed it. Don't know why I forgot to add the default copy constructor. Thank you :)